# Creating text file with variable

Tags: gnome-terminal, users

I want to create a text file in my home directory that is named like the user which is using the terminal, but it mustn't be hard coded, so I think I have to use variables or something. Can someone help?

Comment: Try `touch ~/$(whoami).txt`

Comment: @Raffa ty very much, it worked